# Problema con Codeigniter y csrf_protection

Tags: codeigniter, web, formularios, seguridad

¿Alguien podria ayudarme?

Tengo un problema con la implementación de ***csrf_protection en Codeigniter***:

1. Mi servidor tiene *certificado HTTPS* instalado
2. En los formularios, se está incluyendo el input con el token que genera *Codeigniter*
3. En las *peticiones ajax con codeigniter* tambien se está incluyendo este token

El problema es que, en ocaciones me da error:

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Tambien, al pasar un ***software para detectar vulnerabilidades en codigo***, este me dice que los formularios no tienen ***protección contra csrf***, pero si la tiene (*Siguiendo la documentación oficial de Codeigniter*)

¿Alguien le ha pasado esto y tambien ha tenido problemas con ***csrf_protection en Codeigniter***?

Answer (score 0):

hola encontre una web sobre el CRSF que creo que podria ayudarte

https://arjunphp.com/how-to-enable-csrf-cross-site-request-forgery-codeigniter/